# Codeigniter routing causes function to be called multiple times

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have a function called "insert" in my categories controller. When I call the function via url like this: /categories/insert it works OK, but if I call the function like this: /categories/insert/ (slash at the end) the function is called three times.

Even when a call my edit function like this: /categories/edit/2 - the edit function is called three times.

In config/routes.php I only have default route. My .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|include|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

EDIT:

The code for the edit function:

```
public function edit($id = '') 
{
    $this->load->helper("form");
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $data["title"] = "Edit category";

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_name', 'Category name', 'required');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data['category'] = $this->categories_model->get_categories($id);
        $this->load->view("templates/admin_header", $data);
        $this->load->view("categories/edit", $data);
        $this->load->view("templates/admin_footer", $data); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->categories_model->update($id);
        // other logic
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you say its called three times? can you post your code?

Comment: I know, because I have a breakpoint on the first line of the code. I edited my original post with the code of the function. I don't think that it has anything to do with the code, because when I call the insert function without the slash at the end of the url, it works fine.

Comment: What does your route look like?

Answer (score 1):

** Edit **
`http://your.dot.com/insert` calls public function insert($arg) without data for $arg.
`http://your.dot.com/insert/` calls insert with 'index.php' as $arg.

routes.php

```
$route['edit/(:any)'] = 'edit/$1'
```

Accepts any param coming from the query string: **yoursite.com/edit/param** or **yoursite.com/edit/2**
It requires a method named **edit**.

If you are using `$route=['default_controller'] = 'foo'`, as a container for all of your methods, change the route to `$route['edit/(:any)'] = 'foo/edit/$1'` or something like: `$route['(:any)'] = 'foo/$1/$2'` as the last line of your routes (note: this would work for **yoursite.com/insert/param** and **yoursite.com/edit/param**.

```
foo.php

    public function insert() { ... }

    public function edit($id=null) { ... }

    /* End of file foo.php */


.htaccess

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: If I call only one view, it load's the function once, like is should. But I need that template and this is the way that it is done in the official CI tutorials. This is my edit function. Why my insert function is called once if I don't have slash at the end of the url and three times when i put a slash? I also have three views in my insert function.

Comment: with the slash, it's probably looking for `/index.php`, or the method is trying to run with whatever argument it expects after the slash. See edit.

Comment: I just looked through my base.php controller for my site. I'm using the HMVC pattern, and templates, so I'm not loading views like you are.

Comment: OK, thanks. Any idea how to set my .htaccess or routes.php, so when I call /categories/edit/2, the edit function is not called three times? I don't want to set routing rules for every controller. I will, but only if that's the only solution.

Comment: Added my setup to my answer. I have nothing specific to routes or methods inside the .htaccess file.